# End date on google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

Everytime I open google analytics account I get some default date range which is one month from yesterday to yesterday.

Is there a way to set default to be

```
start: some day I define

end:   last possible day there is
```

Comment: Good question. I would also like to know the same. +1

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to set this within analytics.

This post seems to cover the same topic [Change Default date range](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google%20Analytics/thread?tid=5c996a9e15eada28&hl=en). You could take the same idea open a dashboard with a date range set then remove the end date and bookmark. This could give the result you are after - i did a simple test and it seemed to work.